# How to show that $\{N(\theta,1):\theta \in \Omega\}$ is not a complete family of distributions when $\Omega$ is finite?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, exponential-family, complete-statistics

Consider the $\{N(\theta,1):\theta \in \Omega\}$ family of distributions where $\Omega=\{-1,0,1\}$. I am trying to show that this is not a complete family.  That is, if $X\sim N(\theta,1)$, I need to find a non-zero function $g$ for which $E_{\theta}[g(X)]=0$ for every $\theta \in \mathbb \Omega$.

Now,

$$E_{\theta}[g(X)]=0,~~\forall\,\theta \iff \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)e^{-(x-\theta)^2/2}\,dx=0,~~\forall\, \theta.$$

But any $g$, I can think of depends on $\theta$. I realize $g$ must be chosen in a way such that the elements of $\Omega$ are among the solutions of the equation $E_{\theta}[g(X)]=0$. How does one come up with an appropriate choice of $g$ from the above equation? A hint would be great.

The source of the problem is Ex.21 (page 23) of [this](https://www.stat.purdue.edu/%7Edasgupta/expfamily.pdf) note where I have modified the parameter space to make things slightly simpler.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For notational convenience, let $\varphi_{\theta}(x)$ denote the density of a $N(\theta, 1)$ random variable.

One way of viewing this problem is that the condition
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)\varphi_\theta(x)dx = 0, \quad \theta \in \{-1, 0, 1\} \tag{1}
\end{align*}
sets up a system of three equations. If we pick up $g(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$ from the family of cubic polynomials, then $(1)$ becomes a homogeneous system of three linear equations with four unknowns $a, b, c, d$.  By linear algebra theory, the dimensionality of the solution space to such a linear system is at least $1$ (because the rank of the associated coefficient matrix is at most $3$), implying that there are countless non-zero $g(x)$ satisfying $(1)$.

Indeed, substituting $g(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$ and central moments of $\varphi_\theta(x)$ into $(1)$ yields
\begin{align*}
b + d &= 0, \\
4a + 2b + c + d &= 0, \tag{2} \\
-4a + 2b - c + d &= 0. 
\end{align*}
One (of infinitely many) non-zero solution to $(2)$ is $a = -1, b = 0, c = 4, d = 0$, resulting $g(x) = -x^3 + 4x \neq 0$.  This shows that the family $\{N(\theta, 1): \theta \in \Omega\}$ is not complete.

---

While the above construction works well for any parameter space with finite cardinality, it does not generalize to the case where the parameter space contains infinite members (e.g., the original linked exercise whose $\Omega = \{1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$). To deal with the latter case, note that, by the translation property of $\varphi_\theta$, the condition $E_\theta[g(X)] = 0$ for all $\theta \in \Omega$ is equivalent to
\begin{align}
E[g(X + \theta)] = 0 \; \text{for all } \theta \in \Omega, \tag{2}
\end{align}
where "$E$" is with respect to the standard normal density $\varphi(x)$.  This observation implies that, when $\Omega = \{1, 2, \ldots\}$, $(2)$ automatically holds for $g$ such that $g(x + \theta) = g(x)$ for all $\theta = 1, 2, \ldots$ **and** $E[g(X)] = 0$. Clearly, one candidate of such $g$ is any periodic odd function with periodicity $1$.  For example, $g(x) = \sin(\pi x)$ proposed in @jld's answer.  As another (non-trigonometric) example, $g(x)$ can be taken to be
\begin{align}
g(x) = \frac{1}{2} - \left|x - \frac{1}{2}\right|, \; 0 \leq x \leq 1. 
\end{align}
And then copy this to intervals $[n, n + 1]$, $n = 1, 2, \ldots$ to complete $g$'s definition on $[0, +\infty)$.  Finally, define $g(x) = -g(-x)$ when $x < 0$.

Comment: The thing that I like is the motivation comes naturally and is not contrived: you get a homogenous system of three equations and then ... +1.

Comment: +1 great principled approach!

Answer (score 5):

We can use a function $f$ that is odd about each point in $\Omega$ since then $\int_{\mathbb R} f(x) e^{-(x-\theta)^2}\,\text dx = 0$ for each $\theta$. This suggests a periodic function and so we can get an example by picking a sine wave with frequency high enough to be odd about each $\theta$, so e.g. in your case $\sin (\pi x)$ does the trick.